# Automatic method call printing of executed C++ application

Tags: c++, debugging

I was wondering if anyone knows a way of printing out all the function calls that a C++ application executes. It would be similar to the linux command `strace` or `ltrace`, except that it would print out not only the system calls, but also the normal function calls, destructor calls, copy construction, methods, etc...

Basically just like GDB is doing it when you `step` and then print the stack, except that this would be automatic...

Comment: what is your hard drive's capacity?

Comment: @justin no kidding. was just thinking the same thing.

Comment: I think the only way is to manually call logger API.

Comment: @justin: I have around 1TB free space... can get more if required :P I don't plan to run it on our whole production code, jus small "test" applications to be able to prove some theories about how some methods are called :)

Comment: jokes aside, even logging allocations via `malloc` with backtraces (as one example) can produce huge files in very little time.

Comment: @fritzone hahaha :) i can't answer your question, but the best alternative i can suggest is a time/cpu sampler (e.g. profiler) at a very very high frequency.

Comment: @fritzone but if you want to focus on specific sets of calls, you might just add that to the program where it is required.

Comment: I'm more interested in the hidden function calls... (automatic temporary object creation, destruction, and the order and place when these are called)

Comment: It's not going to help you. If you get a log file with a billion lines, how are you going to find anything interesting?

Comment: patience? you are a programmer; this output is almost always interpreted/filtered by programs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`-finstrument-functions`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html):

> `-finstrument-functions` Generate instrumentation calls for entry and exit to functions. Just after function entry and just before function
>   exit, the following profiling functions will be called with the
>   address of the current function and its call site. (On some platforms,
>   `__builtin_return_address` does not work beyond the current function, so the call site information may not be available to the profiling
>   functions otherwise.)
>
> ```
>       void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
>                                      void *call_site);
>       void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
>                                      void *call_site);
> ```
>
> The first argument is the address of the start of the current function, which may be looked up exactly in the symbol table.
>
> This instrumentation is also done for functions expanded inline in
>   other functions. The profiling calls will indicate where,
>   conceptually, the inline function is entered and exited. This means
>   that addressable versions of such functions must be available. If all
>   your uses of a function are expanded inline, this may mean an
>   additional expansion of code size. If you use `extern inline' in your
>   C code, an addressable version of such functions must be provided.
>   (This is normally the case anyways, but if you get lucky and the
>   optimizer always expands the functions inline, you might have gotten
>   away without providing static copies.)
>
> A function may be given the attribute no_instrument_function, in which
>   case this instrumentation will not be done. This can be used, for
>   example, for the profiling functions listed above, high-priority
>   interrupt routines, and any functions from which the profiling
>   functions cannot safely be called (perhaps signal handlers, if the
>   profiling routines generate output or allocate memory).

There are tools that do this out-of-the-box like [etrace](http://ndevilla.free.fr/etrace/)

Comment: PS. since you mention GDB I assumed you use gcc